# Error posting 'form' data in jqGrid in JSON format. What is correct synthax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am trying to post data to the action method in the postData section in jqGrid like this, but get an error, any ideas?

```
     postData: { species: function() 
                                    {
                                        return JSON.stringify($("form"));
                                    },
```

I can tell you that this format below **does** work but it is not JSON:

```
postData: { species: $("form").serialize() },
```

Comment: actually, now that I look closer, I don't specifically see an error. However, it does not enter my action method eventhough I have a breakpoint.

Comment: One thing to add...I don't know if it matters but when I type JSON.stringify I do not get any intelisense.  Not sure if I'm supposed to or not. I did add the script reference to my main _layout page:  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/json2.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should use [jQuery.serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) instead of [jQuery.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

```js
postData: {
    species: function() {
        return JSON.stringify($("form").serializeArray());
    }
}
```

See also [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8568113/315935) for some more version of data conversion of the data returned from `$("form").serializeArray()` before calling of `JSON.stringify`.