# JQGrid - how to use inline editing?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

When a user selects a row on the JQGrid, he should be able to edit the editable fields and then press the Enter key which will post the row to the controller method which will update the database.
I cannot find how to post the updated data to do this.
I want to send the businessUnitId field and the editable fields as parameters to the controller mether to do this.
This is my webpage;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Maintenance
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Maintenance of Departments and Divisions</legend>
        <p>Add, edit or delete a department or division: <%: Html.DropDownList("BusinessUnitTypes")%></p>
        <p>To amend the department or division, select the row, make the change and then press the return key.</p>
        <table id="list" class="scroll"></table>
        <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;font-size: 11px;"></div>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- "BusinessUnitTypeId", (SelectList)ViewData["BusinessUnitTypes"] -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { reloadGrid(); });

    $('#BusinessUnitTypes').change(function () {
        $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
    });

    function reloadGrid() {
        var lastSelectedId;

        $('#list').jqGrid({
            url: '<%: Url.Action("GetBusinessUnits", "BusinessUnit")%>',
            postData: {
                businessUnitTypeId: function () { return $("#BusinessUnitTypes option:selected").val(); }
            },
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['ID', 'Name', 'Fax', 'Email', "Employees"],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'BusinessUnitId', index: 'BusinessUnitId', width: 25, editable: false },
                { name: 'BusinessUnitName', index: 'BusinessUnitName', width: 200, editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                { name: 'Fax', index: 'Fax', width: 80, align: 'right', edittype: 'text', editable: true },
                { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 200, editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                { name: 'NumberOfEmployees', index: 'NumberOfEmployees', width: 70, editable: false}],
            rowNum: 20,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: $('#pager'),
            sortname: 'BusinessUnitName',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            caption: "Edit",
            height: 575,
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                if (id && id !== lastSelectedId) {
                    $('#list').restoreRow(lastSelectedId);
                    $('#list').editRow(id, true);
                    lastSelectedId = id;
                }
            },
            editurl: '<%: Url.Action("Save", "BusinessUnit")%>'
        });
    }

</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `editable` values and the rowid will be * automatically* send to the URL specified by `editurl` if the user save the data by pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

It seems to me that `BusinessUnitId` is the native unique `id` for the grid. You don't posted any test data which you use to fill the grid. If you would fill `id` with the same value as `BusinessUnitId` has the problem can by automatically solved because the value of `BusinessUnitId` will be sand as `id` value to `editurl`. Alternatively you can add `key: true` property to the definition of `BusinessUnitId` in `colModel`.

If it will not solve your problem you can use `extraparam` to send additional data during saving of the row. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10396691/315935) for details.

I recommend you additionally to add `gridview: true` option to the grid and change `pager: $('#pager')` to `pager: '#pager'`. It will improve the performance.

Comment: Setting key: true populated the id field with the correct value. Thank you for that. I also appreciate the other tips you gave me.

Comment: @arame3333: You are welcome! I would recommend you additionally to use `$(this)` instead of `$('#list')` inside of jqGrid callbacks like `onSelectRow`. It will make the code not only a little bit quickly, but mostly make it more manageable. You will be more easy to use cut&paste of the code if you will need in in another project.