# jqGrid onSelectRow doesn't work

Tags: c#, jqgrid

I want to do some action after inline edit but when I use this code, after edit the row just stuck in edit mode. If I delete `onSelectRow`, row edit works perfectly.

```
onSelectRow: function(rowid){

    $(grid_selector).jqGrid('editRow', rowid, true, null, null, null, {}, aftersavefunc);

    function aftersavefunc(rowid, result) {
        alert("X"); 
        $(grid_selector).trigger("reloadGrid");
    }
},
```

Comment: Do you get the `alert("X");` popup continuously while it's stuck in edit mode?

Comment: no I don't get any alert.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you wrote:

> If I delete `onSelectRow`, row edit works perfectly.

It sound suspected because you *start* row editing inside of `editRow`. If inline editing still work after you delete `onSelectRow` callback then you should search for *other part* of your code where `editRow` will be called directly of indirectly. For example you could use `formatter: "actions"` or `inlineNav` which starts `editRow` for you. To inform jqGrid to use your `aftersavefunc` you have to use corresponding parameters of `inlineNav` or `formatter: "actions"`. For example `inlineNav` provide `editParams` and `addParams` options. Typically one defines **one set** op inline editing parameters (see `editOptions` variable in the code below) and one uses it in both direct and indirect call of `editRow`:

```
var editOptions = {
        keys: true,
        successfunc: function () {
            var $self = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $self.trigger("reloadGrid");
            }, 50);
        }
    },
    $grid = $("#list");

$grid.jqGrid({
    ...
    onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
        $(thus).jqGrid("editRow", rowid, editOptions);
    }
});

$grid.jqGrid("navGrid", "#pager", { edit: false, add: false });

$grid.jqGrid("inlineNav", "#pager", {
    addParams: {
        position: "last",
        addRowParams: editOptions
    },
    editParams: editOptions
});
```

By the way one can click original Edit button added by `inlineNav` instead of calling `editRow` directly. See [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10396691/315935) for the corresponding code example (inside of `onSelectRow` callback).